# Задача по Python

Tags: python

Необходимо вывести в обратном порядке вводимые значения, которые могут быть как цифрами, так и строками или списками.
Пробовал делать изначально через:

```python
import sys
n = (sys.argv[1:])
print ' '.join(n[::-1])
```

Однако так сохраняются скобки, запятые и т.д.
К примеру, при вводе `['force', 'the', 'Feel']`, должно выводиться: `Feel the force`.
При `qwe asd zxc 123` - `123 zxc asd qwe`.

Comment: `print ' '.join(['force', 'the', 'Feel'][::-1])` выводит `Feel the force` без скобок и запятых.

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
import re

input_line = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
output_line = ' '.join(re.split('\W+', input_line)[::-1])
print output_line.strip()
```

Для Вашего примера сработает.
Вообще, задача поставлена не совсем корректно. Мой скрипт сначала объединяет все аргументы командной строки в одну строку через пробел, потом разбивает полученную строку по всем "несловарным символам". Непонятно, что вы хотите получить при запуске программы `python script.py for+ce the Fe-el`? Мой вариант выдаст в этом случае `el Fe the ce for`, т.к. `+` не является частью слова.
Просто если запускать `python script.py ['feel', 'the', 'force']` то "вводимыми данными" будут строки `[feel`, `the,`, `force]`, по крайней мере в *nix.

Еще один вопрос на засыпку:

```
python script.py [1, 2, [3, 4, 5]]
```

Результат:

```
a) [3, 4, 5] 2 1
b) [[5, 4, 3], 2, 1]
c) 5 4 3 2 1
```

Все три варианта, в той или иной степени, подходят.

П.С. Регулярные выражения - одна из самых сложных теи для начинающего, сорри.

Курсы, которые предлагают

```
list.reverse()
result = list[0]
for item in list[1:]:
    result += ' ' + item
```

вместо

```
result = ' '.join(list[::-1])
```

следует немедленно сжечь на костре священной инквизиции

Comment: Условия задачи не мои. Такая указана в одном из курсов. Просто сколько вариантов не пробовал, никак не удавалось при введении списка вывести исключительно слова, избавившись от лишних знаков.

Comment: Как раз мой скрипт и переставит "исключительно слова" в меру понимания питоном термина "слово". Слова могут состоять из букв, цифр и символа `_`, разделенных любыми другими символами.

Comment: Поскольку в условиях нет символов, Ваш вариант подходит. Но, в целом, ответ создателей курса отличается.

Comment: args = sys.argv[1:]
args.reverse()
result = args[0]
for item in args[1:]:
    result = result + ' ' + item

print result

Comment: Это не уберет знаки препинания. Без использования регулярок их не убрать. Просто сделайте `for a in sys.argv[1:]: print a` и посмотрите, что записывается в `sys.argv` в разных вариантах. Это просто вся строка, разделенная пробельными символами.

Comment: Действительно, Вы правы, я и забыл прогнать, чтобы посмотреть как работает. Ну вот такие курсы нынче по Python. Сидишь ломаешь часами голову, а в итоге такое :)

Comment: Ваш исходный код практически ничем не отличается от приведенного в последнем комментарии, кроме того, что ваш гораздо лучше (более pythonic)

Comment: Зачем нужны курсы по такому языку, как питон??? Саммерфилд, Лутц и 2 недели при базовых знаниях в программировании.

Comment: Ну я изучаю полностью с нуля, не имея за спиной никаких знаний или опыта программирования)